# How to make an svg masked image compatible with firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I have some svg masked images that work perfectly in Chrome but does not work in Firefox. Basically my svg gives a shape to the image that the css is applied to and the end result is this .

[image: End Result]

This is my svg code

```
<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 160 160">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M10,70 Q0,80 10,90 L70,150 Q80,160 90,150 L150,90 Q160,80 150,70 L90,10 Q80,0 70,10z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src='http://i.imgur.com/NR6kefg.jpg' class='photo_rectangle_inverse' />
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/DXaH323.jpg' class='photo_rectangle_inverse' />
```

And this is my css

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.photo_rectangle_inverse {
  height: 160px;
  width: 170px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#shape);
  clip-path: url(#shape);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px)
}
```

Here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manofgod/omat2km1/) of all that. This works perfectly in Chrome but not In the latest version of Firefox as at now on windows (FF 40.0.2) .

I went to this [Firefox article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG) but could not find why this is not working in Firefox ?

**How to make this svg masked image compatible with firefox ?**

Thanks

Comment: Works in Firefox 39.0 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Works also in FF 40.0 mac and according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility it should work since 3.5

Comment: It is not working in the latest version of Firefox on windows . FF 40.0.2

Comment: I just tried the jsfiddle on FF 40.0.2 on Windows and it works for me there too.

Comment: @RobertLongson Amazingly it does not work for me. So do you see the shape or just and image displayed ? For me it shows only an image.

Comment: two images clipped by squares rotated by 45 degrees with rounded corners. Basically the same as the screenshot in the question. Removing the clip-path displays the complete images.